# How to display unicode character in emacs

Tags: emacs

I use terminal based emacs latest on ubuntu.

in the terminal unicode characters display fine. But in emacs when I insert a unicode for example `C-x 8 RET` and some hex `455` it displays as `\u0455`.

I had this same problem that I fixed before, but I don't remember how.

Comment: What's your locale?  [ E.g. what do you get when you type just `locale` in a terminal?  ]

Comment: Here's my extended question further investigated http://superuser.com/questions/939312/cygwin-mintty-unicode-doesnt-display-fail-despite-having-dejavu-sans-mono-and-e

Comment: How's that related?  One is with echo in cygwin the other is with Emacs in Ubuntu.

Comment: I ssh into ubuntu using cygwin's mintty terminal @Stefan, Since I can't display greek letter lambda on mintty I assume that's the main problem.