# Cygwin Mintty unicode doesn't display fail despite having dejavu sans mono and everything

Tags: windows, ubuntu, emacs, cygwin, mintty

**Edit**

the problem is ubuntu machine can't display `\u03bb` as greek lambda symbol

ubuntu is remote:

```
[ubuntu@ubuntu:~]$echo -e "\xce\xbb\x0a" 
λ 

[ubuntu@ubuntu:~]$echo -e "\u03bb" 
\u03BB
```

this is local:

```
matizmabel@Casper ~ 
$ echo -e "\u03bb" 
λ 

matizmabel@Casper ~ 
$ echo -e "\xce\xbb" 
λ 

matizmabel@Casper ~ 
$
```

I use cygwin mintty terminal.

I use `Dejavu Sans Mono` and this:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I ssh into ubuntu headless server, and have this issue.
Please fix my unicode display problem.

Comment: any luck with     `$ echo -e "\u03bb"`  Doing \x might be just for when it's two nibbles like `\x41`

Comment: edited, @barlop nop

Comment: Strange. BTW I have the same as you for my locale http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=52cKQhem

Comment: can you display greek letter lambda? @barlop, I used to display it before but time has passed now I it can't.

Comment: yes. What is your version of echo?   http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=d0PgZ47E

Comment: `8.15` http://pastebin.com/NE8JjWZ7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25736/discussion-between-barlop-and-facebook).

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165059/how-to-set-lang-in-locale-despite-its-in-etc-default-locale-in-ubuntu-for-uni

Comment: Please remove the `emacs` tag, since it has nothing to do with Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

Unicode code point = U+039B

character =  Λ

UTF-8 (hex.) = ce 9b

```
 $ echo -e "\xCE\x9B"

 Λ
```

If the problem is remote only, likely that "echo" don't undeerstand the "\u039B" escape. Please note that "\u" is not reported as escape sequence in echo coreutils manuals. nor in POSIX

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

To check it

```
$ echo -ne "\xce\xbb" |od -x
0000000 bbce
0000002


$  echo -ne "\u03bb" |od -x
0000000 bbce
0000002
```